# Ajax success disappearing not displaying

Tags: php, ajax, form-submit

I am having some code here. the ajax success is not displaying. instead it was just displaying and disappearing in fraction of seconds. where the problem lies

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
       <meta name="description" content="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" id="resultform">
          <input type="text" name="rollno" id="rollno" maxlength="6" placeholder="rollno" required />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="tabledata">
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#resultform').submit(function(){
                   var roll=$('#rollno').val();
                   $.ajax({
                       type:'POST',
                       url:'result.php',
                       data:'roll_id='+roll,
                       success:function(data)
                       {
                          $('#tabledata').html(data);
                       }
                      });
                     });
                   });
             </script>
         </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: is it reloading the page?

Comment: yes it is reloading

Comment: You need to prevent the automatic form submission. Modify your submit trigger as :   ..submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ........

Comment: yeah its working fine. but the input contains the number. how to clear the input value entered

Comment: Replace the input value with an empty string in your success function ```$('#rollno').val('');```

Comment: @PAVAN your problem is solved?

Answer (score 1):

Using `$('#resultform').submit` will lead to reload the page after clicking on the form submit button and I think here is your problem, the ajax request is completed successfully but once it's done the page is reloading so the content of your web page will be reset.

Try to add ajax call to a separate button other than the submit one with normal `click` event

Answer (score 1):

Use `return false;` at the end of the `submit()` callback to prevent the the form from submitting

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#resultform').submit(function(){
        var roll=$('#rollno').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'result.php',
            data:'roll_id='+roll,
            success:function(data) {
                $('#tabledata').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or you can pass the event as an argument to the callback and call `preventDefault()` on the event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#resultform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var roll=$('#rollno').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'result.php',
            data:'roll_id='+roll,
            success:function(data) {
                $('#tabledata').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As explained in the docs here https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: what this return false will do

Comment: Stop the form submitting and reloading the page